# How to annotate Page<Foo> for generate correct response

Tags: java, swagger

RestController return response

```
Page<Foo>
```

I annotate like this

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(
            responseCode = "200",

            content = @Content(
                    mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                    array = @ArraySchema(
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = Foo.class)
                    )),
            description = "The request has succeeded")
```

but i need to generate page instead of array.

Is there any way to do this

if should be look like this

```
schema PageFoo->data-> [{Foo}]
```

if i remove annotation it will generate right schema but without  content-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(
        responseCode = "200",
        content = @Content(
            mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            schema = @Schema(implementation = PageFoo.class)
        ),
        description = "The request has succeeded"
    )
})


class PageFoo {
    @Schema(name = "data", implementation = Foo.class, type = SchemaType.ARRAY)
    List<Foo> data;
    //...
}
```